# How to save session() value " " in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In `app.js` -> `methods` i have  `this.chat.image.push('');` and in `axios.post send` i have

```
    methods:{
    send(){
        if(this.message.length != 0)
        {
            this.chat.message.push(this.message);
            this.chat.user.push('');
            this.chat.image.push('');
            this.chat.time.push('');
            axios.post('admin/send', {
                message : this.message,
                chat:this.chat
              })
              .then(response => {
                // console.log(response);

                this.message = '';
              })
        }    
    },
    getOldMessages(){
        axios.post('admin/getOldMessage')
              .then(response => {
                if (response.data != '') {
                    this.chat = response.data;
                }
              })
    },
```

And in `mounted()` i have

```
    mounted(){
    this.getOldMessages();
    Echo.channel('chat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            this.chat.message.push(e.message);
            this.chat.user.push(e.user);               
         this.chat.image.push('source/admin/assets/images/avatar/'+e.image);
            axios.post('admin/saveToSession',{
                chat : this.chat
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
        })
    })
}
```

In `Controller` i have function `saveToSession`

```
    public function saveToSession(request $request)
    {
        session()->put('chat',$request->chat);
    }
```

In `send() function` i get `image=" ";` but when I save to the session it returns null, How come it returns to the value `= " "` ? Thanks

Comment: Laravel has middleware that trims strings and converts empty strings to null.

Comment: What should I do to make the null  to trims string ? thanks :D

Comment: Disable the middleware if you really want to but I don't really see why you'd care about an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Check that value in $request->chat are coming properly or not if yes then you can try other methods as well

**Via a request instance**

*$request->session()->put('key', 'value');*

**Via the global helper**

session(['key' => 'value']);

Comment: When i check session 'chat' I get array {"message":["Hello"],"user":[null],"color":["#e8e8e8"],"badge":["#80827f"],"area":["left"],"image":[null],"time":[null]}, I don't understand ,why value ' ' be null @@

Comment: make $data = $request->all() and then use the data for next operations. 

for example
$data = {"message":["Hello"],"user":[null],"color":["#e8e8e8"],"badg‌​e":["#80827f"],"area‌​":["left"],"image":[‌​null],"time":[null]}‌​;

session(message => $data['message']);

 and which value you are getting null? Please put your HTML code as well.